# SQL count and group only returns first row for each group

Tags: php, sql

My table:

```
+----------+---------------------+  
| bonus_id | created             |  
+----------+---------------------+  
|  11      | 2020-04-28 19:50:13 |  
|  12      | 2020-04-29 00:00:00 |  
|  13      | 2020-04-30 19:55:58 |  
|  14      | 2020-04-29 19:56:07 |  
|  15      | 2020-04-30 19:56:18 |  
|  16      | 2020-04-29 20:16:21 |  
+----------+---------------------+
```

This is what I'm **trying** to get

```
2020-04-30 - Count: 2
13
15
2020-04-29 - Count: 3
12
14
16
2020-04-28 - Count: 1
11
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
2020-04-30 - Count: 2
13
2020-04-29 - Count: 3
12
2020-04-28 - Count: 1
11
```

My code:

```
SELECT DATE(created) as created, COUNT(*) as count, bonus_id FROM test WHERE account_id=? AND user_id=? GROUP BY DATE(created) DESC
```

I'm getting the correct order with all the outpounts when i use ORDER BY and not GROUP/COUNT, but then I'm not getting the count. Don't understand why I'm only getting the first row for each date.

Comment: Your query is broken.  `bonus_id` is not aggregated and not in the `GROUP BY`.  In any reasonable database, you would get a syntax error.  Tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a column with the count to each row, use window functions:

```
select t.*, count(*) over (partition by date(created)) as day_cnt
from test t;
```

If you want an aggregated list, then I'll assume you are using MySQL (an old version) or SQLite because these do not generate a syntax error.  In that case, you can use `group_concat()`:

```
select date(created), count(*), group_concat(bonus_id) as bonus_ids
from test
group by date(created);
```

Comment: Yeah. Weird about that error. Got version MariaDB 10.4.10. Anyway thank you for the help that worked.